# How do I delay Outlook 2007 and my phone app. until Commodo has booted?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007, anti-virus

Win 7.

Outlook 2007, vBuzzer and Skype are set to boot automatically. I don't want them to be active until my AV, Comodo has finished booting. How can I set that up?

Comment: You can't really control this. You can make a script that starts this, and calculate how much you have to wait, then insert a delay, but its not going to be really accurate. Since Comodo won't launch at exactly the same speed at every boot, its possible that one time its still loading while your other programs open, or the other time they are done loading and it takes a bit before your other programs start. Its just not possible.

Comment: Hack it...  Don't let them start up immediately, instead run a script 1 minute after boot completes to start the programs....  Maybe a loop in a powershell script to check if comodo is running before hand....

Comment: @Dave you can't really measure if comodo is running. Technically comodo runs as soon as you start the program. It just has to initialize first, and I'm pretty sure Xavierjazz wants to know the moment comodo is ready for usage, not when the program is known to be running to the system. Perhaps you can monitor CPU usage but even that is pretty buggy to use.